# Call java-Agent of another DataBase from current DataBase Java-Agent

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino, agent

I have a java-agent from which I can call another agent with the parameter passed through it which contains NoteId, and using that NoteId, I am successfully able to get the work done the that document.Till here every thing is clear.

The main question regarding this is , Is it possible to run the agent of another database on same server from the current database agent?

To be more clear for an example 
I have two databases, "ABC.nsf" and "XYZ.nsf", JavaAgent "A" is in "ABC.nsf" and JavaAgent "B" is in "XYZ.nsf". In my xpage I have a button running Agent "A", and even Agent "A" can run any other javaAgent from the same database.

Code:

```
 Document mainDoc = db.getDocumentByUNID(tempDoc.getItemValueString("mainDocId"));
 String noteID = mainDoc.getNoteID();
 String agentName = "NotificationManager";
 Agent agent = db.getAgent(agentName);
 if (agent != null) 
     agent.runOnServer(noteID);
 else 
    System.err.println("Something is wrong");
```

But Actually I want run the JavaAgent "B" Located in "XYZ.nsf" from JavaAgent "A" which is in "ABC.nsf".

After some research I have referd this code.
Code

```
Database db=session.getDatabase(current_server, "path/to/XYZ.nsf"); 
Agent myAgent=db.getAgent("B"); 
myAgent.run();
```

And yes I am unsuccessfull there,
Need some idea to acheive this.Any suggession will be really appretiated.

Comment: Did you really write `db=session.getDatabase(current_server, path/to/XYZ.nsf);` or did you use quotes like this : `db=session.getDatabase(current_server, "path/to/XYZ.nsf");`? And: does the variable `current_server` contain the right servername? And: Is this a linux- server or a windows server (slash or backslah)? is the path relative to data directory?

Comment: oh sorry it typing mistake i have written "path/to/XYZ.nsf".

Comment: please share exact error message/exception stacktrace you get

Answer (score 3):

The example code is correct in principle. Just some things you have to know:

First of all the name of server can either be "" or the real name of the server. BUT if there is a server, then you have to check the `Trusted servers:`- section in the server document (Security Tab - Server Access section). There the server himself has to be member of the field (as name or in a group), otherwise you might  not be able to open the other database.

Second thing: the path to the target database is relative to data directory and has to be in the right format for the given operating system.

e.g. `C:\IBM\Domino\Data\first\xyz.nsf` would be `first\xyz.nsf` and `/local/notesdata/second/abc.nsf`would be `second/abc.nsf`

Third: the noteid that you get is from a document from the calling database. In the "target"- agent you have to go and get the document from the source database, otherwise it will either throw an error or -as the noteid is just a sequential number- return a document from target database that has nothing to do with the document you are searching for.

The calling agent A would have code like this:

```
Session session = getSession();
AgentContext agentContext = 
session.getAgentContext();
Database dbCurrent = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
Database dbTarget = session.getDatabase(dbCurrent.Server, "XYZ.nsf"); 
Agent myAgent=dbTarget.getAgent("B"); 
myAgent.runOnServer(noteID);
```

The called agent B could look like this

```
Session session = getSession();
AgentContext agentContext = 
session.getAgentContext();
Database dbCurrent = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
Database dbSource = session.getDatabase(dbCurrent.Server, "ABC.nsf"); 
Document doc = dbSource.getDocumentByID(agentContext.getCurrentAgent().getParameterDocID())
```

This should work (if security is ok on the server). 
As Paul mentioned in the comments security also means that the agent signer or web user (depending on the settings in agent A) has to have sufficient access to the target database AND the target server (if it is different).

If it does not work despite of correct security: Show us the exact error / trace.

Comment: If agent A is running as web user, presumably that same user will also need access to database B, is that right? If so, that could be another area it could fail.

Comment: In his second paragraph, he said he wants to run an agent from another database on the *same* server, therefore he does not need to check the Trusted Servers setting. That only applies when an agent on ServerA needs to access a database on ServerB (and it is ServerB's setting that matters in that case).

Comment: You are most probably right regarding current versions. But when the trusted server setting was intruduced (before that it was not even possible to access other servers with an agent), the code was not very intelligent: Accessing a database with e.g. new NotesDatabase( currentserver, "db.nsf" ) did a check for the servername in the trusted server field, even if it was the same as the current server, while New NotesDatabase( "", "db.nsf" ) did not... But this was probably fixed long time ago, and it was jsut mentioned to get a complete answer...

Comment: Oddly, later in the day yesterday I experienced a problem with an agent running on a client, On a 6.x client, it ran fine. On an 8.5 client, it threw an error, and the $Error value was "To open database (xxx !! yyy.nsf) on remote machines the server where the agent is running has to be listed by remote machine as trusted server"  I've never heard of this happening in client code, and it should not happen. Clearly there is a difference in behavior between 6 and 8.5 LotusScript engines. Very strange.

Comment: I've only found evidence of one other person experiencing this problem cliient-side.I can only understand it partially (thanks to Google translate from Russian), but it's clear that it's the same situation. Code that ran okay on 6 throws the error on 8.5.
http://developer.developer-works.com/article/32085855/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5+%D1%81+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0+Lotus+6.5+%D0%BD%D0%B0+8.5.+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8+(OLE)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a different approach? If you don't need an immediate reply from the agent, as a return value in the code, why don't you send the other database a special mail? Create a mail agent (triggered after new mail has been received), at the sender side create a NotesDocument object, add the values you need to reference the document you want the agent to work on, like the name of the server, the replicaId of the database, and the uniqueId. The agent receives the mail and inspects the fields for what it's supposed to do. The receiving database should be mentioned in the N&A book as Mail-in database.

Advantages are manifold: no hassle with rights, a clear interface, no need to open the other database, the agent is executed by the agent manager at a convenient time, you can easily add more functionality the same way, etc.

Comment: Yes currently I am doing the same till sending the mail to other database and the other database recieves the mail and in that database I have a scheduled agent which runs after given time interval and then processes the new action if contision satisfied, This is going good but I dont want to wait for the schedule agent to run it is increasing my process time.

Comment: Why a scheduled agent? You can set the trigger to When new mail has arrived. Then it will run within a few minutes (configurable using a notes.ini parameters). If you need to run it immediately, use the Before mail has arrived trigger, but execution should be very short in that case.

Comment: Yes,I have done that. Now I have set a parameter in notes.ini "AMgr_DisableMailLookup=1" to disable the mail lookups and it worked, But I have noticed that the agent did not start as soon as after mail is arrived. It is taking some time and then running.Any suggesion this?

Comment: You might set AMgr_NewMailEventDelay to 0, that saves a minute (wow!). There may be others, see the documentation: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.5.3/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_AGENT_MANAGER_NOTES_INI_VARIABLES.html?lang=en